# is that code executing in server side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have Default.aspx page containing ASP.net tags code inside javascript  as follows:

```
<input id='send' text='submit' type='button' />

$('#send').click(function (){
    printable();
    return false ;
});
function printable(){
var html;
<% int X=10; %>
<% if( X <= 10) { %>
    html='<span> the value is less than or equal 10</span>';
<%}else{%>
    html='<span> the value is greater than 10</span>';
<%}%>
$(body).append(html) ;
}
```

My question is:
Is when pressing send button  that asp tags code gone to server side to execute?

Comment: No they will not send

Comment: open the page in your browser and hit the "view source code" button in your right-click-menu, ASP-Code is executed on the server prior to loading the page

Comment: How your question is related to Java/Javascript?

Comment: @PradeepSimha, I guess that he thought that JavaScript initiates the call to the server to execute it own code.
Java is indeed irrelevant. You can edit the post and remove that tag, you know. :)

Comment: I know but I want to make sure OP is aware that's it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, what happens is that ASP.NET (or any server side language) will evaluate the page and will send to the browser raw HTML.

In your case, the browser will get this:

```
<input id='send' text='submit' type='button' />

$('#send').click(function (){
    printable();
    return false ;
});
function printable(){
    var html;
    html='<span> the value is less than or equal 10</span>';
    $(body).append(html) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, according to your generated html code above what happens if I modified the original code to <%int X=15;%> without refresh the page?

Comment: Instead of
`html='<span> the value is less than or equal 10</span>';`

 this would be printed in the HTML:

 `html='<span> the value is greater than 10</span>';`

Comment: function printable(){
    var html;
    html='<span> the value is less than or equal 10</span>';
    $(body).append(html) ;
} this is generated code as you told before, then if we change the X value to 15 and press send button, what will happen?

Comment: `<span>the value is greater than 10</span>` will be printed on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The asp code is executed when you request the page and it will generate a JS code. So when you click on send it just execute the JS code that was generated by the server.